# Can I download Swiffy to use on a network not connected to the Internet?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6, google-swiffy

I work where our network is not and cannot be connected to the Internet.  We have hundreds of Flash AS3 files that need to be converted to HTML5.  We also cannot move the files off of the network to convert them and then return them to the network.  Is it possible to download an executable of Google's Swiffy for use on my closed network?

Comment: There is a server-side component (source currently not public).... refer to their dev site https://developers.google.com/swiffy/

Comment: what is the programming problem here?

Comment: and ultimately try to find another company to work for ....

Answer (score 0):

You can convert swf to Swiffy bytecode only online. But use Swiffy bytecode is possible without online mode. For this you need download runtime.js

Answer (score 0):

**Converting FLAs to Swiffy...**

Google has a Swiffy extension for Flash CS 5 or CS 6 (but not Creative Cloud).

You can get it here: https://developers.google.com/swiffy/convert/flash-extension

Install it in Flash CS 5 or 6. Then, instead of exporting your FLA as SWF, you use `Commands > Export as HTML5 (Swiffy)` to export an HTML file.

**Rendering the Swiffy HTML file offline...**

Download the latest Swiffy renderer from here:
https://www.gstatic.com/swiffy/v7.4/runtime.js

In the Swiffy HTML file you exported from Flash, there'll be a link to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/swiffy/v7.4/runtime.js"></script>
```

Change that link to your local runtime.js file.